# Multiple mysql queries in Joomla eventlist function

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am trying to add a second query to a function. How can I combine those 2 queries? I want to delete a user from the table and change the status of another user from "waiting list" to "regular user". Both queries work if I check them separately.

```
function delreguser()
{
    $user   = & JFactory::getUser();

    $event  = (int) $this->_id;
    $userid = $user->get('id');

    // Must be logged in
    if ($userid < 1) {
        JError::raiseError( 403, JText::_('ALERTNOTAUTH') );
        return;
    }

// update waitinglist
$query ='UPDATE #__eventlist_register SET uwl = 0 where event = '.$event.' AND uwl = 1 ORDER BY uregdate LIMIT 1';

// delete user
$query2 = 'DELETE FROM #__eventlist_register WHERE event = '.$event.' AND uid= '.$userid.'';

    $this->_db->SetQuery( $query);
    $this->_db->SetQuery( $query2);

    if (!$this->_db->query()) {
            JError::raiseError( 500, $this->_db->getErrorMsg() );
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the first query before setting the second one.

```
$this->_db->setQuery($query);
$this->_db->query();
$this->_db->setQuery($query2);
$this->_db->query();
```